Setting up a Solace connection with IBM CDC using JMS
I’m working to establish a connection between IBM Change Data Capture (CDC) and Solace PubSub+ Standard using the JMS API. I placed the necessary Solace JAR files (sol-jms-10.25.1 and sol-common-10.25.1) in the Access Server’s lib directory, but IBM Management Console doesn’t show a JMS target option. I also added these JARs to the lib directory of the DB2 replication engine in IBM CDC, hoping it would enable direct communication over JMS/TCP.
I installed IBM CDC for the event server and configured the connection with the Solace connection factory, message VPN (as JMS server username), and JNDI context. I set up the JNDI URL with localhost:port, tried using IP directly, and added the same credentials for both JMS and JNDI message destinations. For destinations, I provided a topic name and created the required topics, queues, and connection factory in Solace.
I expected this configuration to enable a smooth connection where IBM CDC captures changes from the source database and publishes them to Solace. However, I’m encountering a "destination error" message.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

It looks like this question was also asked over on the Solace community page where this is an ongoing conversation: https://solace.community/discussion/4024/setting-up-a-solace-connection-with-ibm-cdc-using-jms

I have connected to Solace using a test user provided by Solace, and the events are being published on the topics. However, I am facing connectivity issues (Java destination error) on the IBM CDC end, and I don’t think there are any issues on the Solace side. I have posted about it on Stack Overflow, so any help would be appreciated.
